# How to define redirect path for unauthenticated users of custom auth guard in Laravel8 using Jetstream and Fortify

Tags: authentication, laravel-8, fortify, laravel-jetstream

I have defined two different auth guards called 'siteusers' and 'staffusers' in my Laravel 8 based portal in which I am using Jetstream and Fortify for session based authentication.

Now, I have two different URL structure for both type of users

1. [www.sitename.com/siteusers/dashboard](http://www.sitename.com/siteusers/dashboard)
2. [www.sitename.com/staffusers/dashboard](http://www.sitename.com/staffusers/dashboard)

I would like to set an algorithm that if someone clicks on 1st link from above (while not logged in) then he should be redirected to

- [www.sitename.com/siteusers/login](http://www.sitename.com/siteusers/login)

If someone clicks on 2nd link (while not logged in) then he should be redirected to

- [www.sitename.com/staffusers/login](http://www.sitename.com/staffusers/login)

Is it possible in Fortify's current version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to app\http\middleware\Authenticate.php

Add Following before starting of the class

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
```

Then replace everyting inside the **redirectTo** function with following code

```
    $routeMiddleware = Route::current()->middleware();
    // Example Output : Array ( [0] => web [1] => auth:siteusers [2] => verified )
    $route = explode(":", $routeMiddleware[1]);
    $routeName = $route[1];
    if (!$request->expectsJson()) {
        if ($routeName == 'siteusers')
            return route('siteusers.login');
        else
            return route('staffusers.login');
    }
```

Assumptions Made:

1. Siteusers Login Route Name : siteusers.login
2. Staffusers Login Route Name : staffusers.login
3. Name of Auth Guard for Siteusers: siteusers

You can replace these values with actual ones

Comment: You have saved my much time. This is the perfect solution.

Comment: In my situation I was looking to change the redirect which occurred if a user was already logged in and trying to access the login page. To do so, simply change the redirect in app\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated.php